# Authenticated HEAD call from Maven to Artifactory

Tags: maven, authentication, artifactory, maven-metadata

I recently activated security on my Artifactory instance which cause several issue. One remains and seems a bit strange:

Maven use HTTP HEAD to check if a new SNAPSHOT has been deployed.
However, when security is enabled, the first call is done without authentication header, resulting in a 401 Response from Artifactory.

Maven is then supposed to perform the same call with an authentication header. This is the case for **maven-metadata.xml** files.

But for *.pom and .jar files*, the request is not re-attempted as shown in the log below:

```
20150303104244|3|REQUEST|xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|non_authenticated_user|GET|/libs-snapshot-local/mycompany/common/common-config/1.0.4-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.1|401|0
20150303104244|12|REQUEST|xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|user|GET|/libs-snapshot-local/mycompany/common/common-config/1.0.4-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.1|200|322
20150303104244|40|REQUEST|xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|user|GET|/libs-snapshot-local/mycompany/common/common-config/1.0.4-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1|HTTP/1.1|200|40
20150303104244|4|REQUEST|xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|user|GET|/libs-snapshot-local/mycompany/common/common-config/1.0.4-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.md5|HTTP/1.1|200|32
20150303104245|2|REQUEST|xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|non_authenticated_user|HEAD|/libs-snapshot-local/mycompany/myproject/myproject-interface/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/myproject-interface-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar|HTTP/1.1|401|0
20150303104245|2|REQUEST|xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|non_authenticated_user|HEAD|/libs-snapshot-local/mycompany/myproject/myproject-interface/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/myproject-interface-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar|HTTP/1.1|401|0
```

As explained the maven-metadata.xml file download is reattempted with user credentials but the **myproject-interface-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar** is not.

I tried to enable the preemtive authentication for that server but I could not find any change in Maven behaviour :

```
    <server>
        <id>snapshot</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>xxx</password>
        <configuration>
            <httpConfiguration>
                <all>
                    <usePreemptive>true</usePreemptive>
                    <params>
                        <property>
                            <name>http.authentication.preemptive</name>
                            <value>%b,true</value>
                        </property>
                    </params>
                </all>
            </httpConfiguration>
        </configuration>
    </server>
```

This only concerns the update of existing SNAPSHOT as downloading new artifacts is done with HTTP GET with contains the autentication header (at least with a retry). This still prevents a correct usage of SNAPSHOT artifacts.

I am using Maven 3.2.1 and Artifactory 3.4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was related to the usage of the "Maven Snapshot Version Behavior" option in the Artifactory snapshot repository.

As explained [here](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-5404), this option is not supported by Maven 3 anymore.

> Maven 3 Only Supports Unique Snapshots
>
> Maven 3 has dropped support for
> resolving and deploying non-unique snapshots. Therefore, if you have a
> snapshot repository using non-unique snapshots, we recommend that
> youchange your Maven snapshot policy to 'Unique' and remove any
> previously deployed snapshots from this repository. The unique
> snapshot name generated by the Maven client on deployment cannot help
> in identifying the source control changes from which the snapshot was
> built and has no relation to the time sources were checked out.
> Therefore,we recommend that the artifact itself should embed the
> revision/tag (as part of its name or internally) for clear and visible
> revision tracking. Artifactory allows you to tag artifacts with the
> revision number as part of its Build Integration support.

Switching to **Unique** solved this issue.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who lands here hoping to enable preemptive authentication by default:

[The documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-http-settings.html#Example:_Using_Preemptive_Authentication) for this setting on the main Maven site is wrong. I spent a while tracking it down but ultimately found the answer on an [open bug ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WAGON-405?focusedCommentId=14459285&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14459285) which I've reproduced below. This worked for Maven 3.1.1 on OS X.

```
<servers>
 <server>
  <id>serverid</id>
  <username>myuser</username>
  <password>mypassword</password>
  <configuration>
   <wagonProvider>httpclient</wagonProvider>
   <httpConfiguration>
    <all>
     <usePreemptive>true</usePreemptive>
    </all>
   </httpConfiguration>
  </configuration>
 </server>
</servers>
```